# Can't get .mp3 to stop using JavaFX media player

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, media-player, scenebuilder

So i'm trying to make a jukebox app using javafx and scenebuilder. It has a keypad in which i type the number of the song into a label, the text on the label is converted to an int and passed to the track() method which picks a track from the array (the array is a placeholder for something fancier in the future)
The play() method plays the track just fine...
Code of the controller class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@FXML
private Label number;

public void zero(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "0");
}

public void one(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "1"); 
}

public void two(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "2");
}

public void three(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "3");
}

public void four(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "4"); 
}

public void five(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "5");     
}

public void six(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "6");     
}

public void seven(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "7"); 
}

public void eight(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "8");     
}

public void nine(ActionEvent event){

    number.setText(number.getText() + "9");
}

public void clear(){
    number.setText("");
}

public MediaPlayer track(){
        URL[] songs = new URL[]{
        getClass().getResource("/res/03. Eyes On Fire.mp3"),
        getClass().getResource("/res/05,Graveyard-Endless Night.mp3"),
        getClass().getResource("/res/10 Nas - It Ain't Hard To Tell.mp3")
};

 final Media media = new Media(songs[Integer.parseInt(number.getText())].toString());
 final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
 return mediaplayer;
}

public void play(){
    track().play();

}

public void stop(){
    track().stop();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No time for a complete answer now, but your `track()` method creates a new `MediaPlayer` every time you call it. So you are calling `stop()` on a different `MediaPlayer` to the one on which you called `play()`. (So the one on which you called `play()` never gets stopped.)

Comment: thanks can't believe i didnt figure that.. but to you have any advice on how to fix it? if i don't use a method to declare mediaplayer i get an error when i try to run the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `track()` method is creating a new `MediaPlayer` every time you call it. So when you call `stop()` you are calling it on a different instance to the one on which you called `play()`, and the one on which you call `play()` never gets stopped.

You need to keep a reference to the "current" `MediaPlayer`. Let `track()` (or perhaps `selectTrack()` update that reference, then you can call `stop()` on it when you need. Something like:

```
public class MainController {

    private MediaPlayer player ;

    // ...

    public void selectTrack() {
        URL[] songs = new URL[] { ... } ;
        final Media media = new Media(songs[Integer.parseInt(number.getText())].toString());
        this.player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    }

    public void play() {
        // stop current player:
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }
        selectTrack();
        player.play();
    }

    public void stop() {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```